# Combine tables with different number of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to UNION two tables that have mostly the same columns, but one has several additional columns. I'm aware that you can do a SELECT with placeholders for those additional columns, but I'm working with about 200 columns, and the bigger table has about 30 additional columns. This makes it unreasonable to type out every column. Is there a way to union the tables while automatically setting a NULL value for the columns that don't exist in the smaller table?

Comment: Nope. Every table in a union MUST have the same number of columns. But if you can make the table with fewer columns second you don't have to name the columns. Just add "null, null, null, null...." to the second query.

Comment: @SeanLange Do I have to add the null columns in the same order as the columns in the larger table?

Comment: Yes. Both queries need to have the same number of columns. The order of columns in the second select statement define which column in the first query it will appear.

Comment: Just use a query on the system tables/views to get all the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no. `Unioning` result sets together must have the same number / data type of columns. If you wanted to have the remaining sets populate null, the simplest way to do this would be to do something like so-

```
select col1
, col2
, col3
, col4
from tbl1

union all

select null as col1
, null as col2
, null as col3
, null as col4
from tbl2
```

Comment: You don't have to name the columns in the second query. The column names are defined in the first query when there is a UNION or UNION ALL. You can alias them whatever you want or not at all, it has no impact on the query.

Comment: Yeah, it is optional. Just for clarity I suggested to have alias.